# CSS prefers-color-scheme does not work on chrome at all

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, content-management-system

I have a wordpress website in which I want to block access to dark mode with

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
body {
    color:white;
    background-color:green;
}
```

After applying the css, I discovered that (on chrome though I haven't try other browsers) users still have access to the dark background mode.

This doesn't solve it, how can I block the black background even with users defined theme set to dark mode?

Note: updated my chrome to the latest version all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the light styles too:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    body {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    body {
        background-color: #000;
    }
}
```

Try that and then ensure you chnage your machines settings from dark to light too.